# Database restore takes 20 minutes longer when run through Agent job vs as T-SQL in a query window

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run this statement in a query window as my own user account, the restore completes in 40 minutes. When I run it as a step in an agent job it runs in over 60 minutes. In the agent job, the step executes as NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. What could cause the time difference?

```
ALTER DATABASE [Example] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE [Example] FROM  DISK = N'D:\Example.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, 
MOVE N'Example' TO N'D:\Example.MDF',  
MOVE N'Example_log' TO N'D:\Example_log.LDF',  
REPLACE, STATS = 10

ALTER DATABASE [Example] SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

Comment: Are you testing the run times at the same time of day?  Hypothesis that your agent job is on a schedule to run at night and it's competing for resources at that time.

Comment: @JonathanFite Or perhaps even waiting on rolling back another process's query because of the `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`, depending on what's running at that time.